# How can I rename all file of a folder like '1.jpg' to '1 hello.jpg' with Linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have thousands of pictures in a folder like this-

```
1.jpg

2.jpg

3.jpg
```

And I want to rename them all to

```
   1 hello.jpg

    2 hello.jpg

    3 hello.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You want the three files to name same?? How exactly?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have tried to find it's solution from Google. But I didn't found any easy way.

Comment: So then you've tried nothing.

Comment: @Vinny No. Not same. First one is `1 hello.jpg` 2nd one is `2 hello.jpg` and 3rd one is `3 hello.jpg`.

Comment: You better change the names without a namespace; it will save you a lot of trouble under Linux

Comment: @Vinny but I want to keep a space between `1` and `hello` that's why I posted this question.

Comment: `man bash`, in particular sections about `for` loop, pattern substitution in parameter expansion and quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in [[:digit:]]*.jpg;do mv $x "${x%.jpg} hello.jpg";done
```

Answer (score 0):

This script would be exactly doing what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *.jpg
do
    oldName=$(basename -s.jpg $f)
    mv $f  $oldName\ hello.jpg
done
```